# TCP 443 listener on AWS Private Network Load balancer throws SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, apache-2.4, https, amazon-elb

I have a `AWS private Network Load Balancer` setup with a listener `TCP 443`, the target group attached to this listener is also running on port 443. The instances attached to this target are running `Apache 2.4` on `Centos 7`.

The web server configuration has been double checked and when I run the below command it works.
Here x.x.x.x is the private IP address of the instance.
`$ curl -kv https://x.x.x.x`
Above command works across the VPC.

But when I use the private NLB domain name:
`$ curl -kv https://some-unique-id.elb.region.amazonaws.com`

It gives the below error:

```
* About to connect() to some-unique-id.elb.region.amazonaws.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* Connected to some-unique-id.elb.region.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* NSS error -12263 (SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG)
* SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

#### Configuration summary

- Instance OS = Centos 7.7
- web server = Apache 2.4
- AWS NLB is internal facing
- NLB has listener `TCP 443`

I have tried it on port 80 and everything works fine but I am facing this issue on 443, I have searched a lot for this and most answers point to out to some configuration on Apache to be missing, but I all of those are already configured in my conf file. Any guidance would be helpful.

```
Listen 443 https

SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>

ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn

SSLEngine on

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA


SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key



SSLVerifyClient none


<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

DocumentRoot /path/to/my/app
    
<Directory "/path/to/my/app">
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI -MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Test your site with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and see if it gives you any recommendations. Report back if you need any help with interpreting the results.

Comment: @MLu Thanks for taking the time to read the question. I have bookmarked this site to debug ssl issues in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging a lot, I found out that I was sending https traffic to a target group which was listening on port 80. That's why the SSL just went to port 80 and never got terminated.

After changing the port 80 to 443 of the target group, everything started working.